# Bash find last entry before timestamp

Tags: bash, grep

I have a .csv file that is formatted thus;

myfile.csv

```
**Date,Timestamp,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Data6**  
20130730,22:08:51.244,APPLES,Spain,67p,blah,blah  
20130730,22:08:51.244,PEARS,Spain,32p,blah,blah  
20130730,22:08:51.708,APPLES,France,102p,blah,blah  
20130730,22:10:62.108,APPLES,Spain,67p,blah,blah  
20130730,22:10:68.244,APPLES,Spain,67p,blah,blah
```

I wish to feed in a timestamp which most likely will NOT match up perfectly to the millisecond with those in the file, and find the preceding line that matches a particular grep search.

so e.g. something like;

```
cat myfile.csv | grep 'Spain' | grep 'APPLES' | grep -B1 "22:09"
```

should return

```
20130730,22:08:51.244,APPLES,Spain,67p,blah,blah
```

But thus far I can only get it to work with exact timestamps in the grep. Is there a way to get it to treat these as a time series? (I am guessing that's what the issue is here - it's trying pure pattern matching and not unreasonably failing to find one)

Comment: Note you are looking for "SPAIN" while the text is "Spain".

Comment: Thanks - imprecise of me but only in the post here. I will amend and clarify

Comment: It is not clear what is failing to you. If I execute this command it returns the expected output + previous line. That is, `22:09:62.108` and `22:08:51.244`.

Comment: I have amended the last two timestamps to 22:10* in order to emphasise the point. I see why you managed to get a match on this data. As you might have guessed, the data I have used is a fabricated example as the actual data is confidential. Sorry for wasting your time a little.

Comment: @Pascoe : the version I read is unclear: you want to have the line "just before" 22:09, yet you say you expect a line which is 3 lines above (ie, why do you expect 22:08:51.244,APPLES, whereas the line just before 22:09 is 22:08:51.708,APPLES ?)

Comment: Because I also grepped for Spain

Comment: @Pascoe: ach, silly me ^^ sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

you could have a awk that keep in memory the last line it saw which have a timestamp lower than the one you feed it, and prints the last match at the end (considering they are in ascending order)

ex:

```
awk  -v FS=',' -v thetime="22:09" '($2 < thetime) { before=$0 ; }  END { print before ; }' myfile.csv
```

This happen to work as you feed it a string that, lexigographically, doesn't need to have the complete size (ie 22:09:00.000) to be compared.

The same, but on several lines for readability:

```
awk  -v FS=',' -v thetime="22:09" '
   ($2 < thetime) { before=$0 ; }  
   END            { print before ; }' myfile.csv
```

Now if I understand your complete requirements: you need to find, among lines mactching a country and a type of product, the last line before a timestamp? then:

```
awk -v FS=',' -v thetime="${timestamp}" -v country="${thecountry}" -v product="${theproduct}" '
   ( $4 == country ) && ( $3 == product ) && ( $2 < thetime ) { before=$0 ; }
   END             { print before ; }'  myfile.csv
```

should work for you... (feed it with 10:07, Spain and APPLES, and it returns the expected "20130730,22:08:51.244,APPLES,Spain,67p,blah,blah" line)

And if your file spans several days (to adress Bentoy13's concern),

```
awk -v FS=',' -v theday="${theday}" -v thetime="${timestamp}" -v thecountry="${thecountry}" -v theproduct="${theproduct}" '
   ( $4 == thecountry ) && ( $3 == theproduct ) && (($1<theday)||(($1==theday)&&($2<thetime))) { before=$0 ; }
   END             { print before ; }'  myfile.csv
```

That last one also works if the first column changes (ie, if it spans several days), but you need to feed it also theday

Comment: Interesting - will explore. The time will need to be passed in as a parameter rather than hard coded but it looks promising. Thanks. Will give +ve feedback once I have working solution. Help is appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: Works well. Now my next task is to feed a list of fruits and a list of timestamps and return, for each given timestamp, the most recent entry for each of the fruits. I will have an attempt at doing this myself before expecting people to spoonfeed me (unless people are desperate to do so)... Have given +ve feedback. good answer...

Comment: to pass as a parameter you just need to change `-v thetime="22:09"` with something like `-v thetime="${variable}"` . it is just basically : `-v awk_variable=some_value` so that you can then use awk_variable inside awk

Comment: Don't work properly in case of date change. I think you have to add a test on $1, because if you want to take the lat line before 00:00, it will surely fail.

Comment: @Bentoy13: it's true, however the OP's example was almost inducing it's all on the same day (so timestamps start low and end high, and never "roll"?), apparently (as he looks only on the time himself) (`grep -B1 "22:09"`) ... but indeed, giving also the day in a separate variable + changing the test to `(($1<theday) || (($1==theday)&&($2<thetime)))` would work in a more general case

Comment: @OlivierDulac Indeed, it's up to the OP to do the change; I think it is valuable to take into account the day. Your updated solution is OK now, so +1 :). Mine seems very complicated now...

Comment: @Bentoy3: your use of mktime and splits will come in handy in lots of situations (especially when the file's timestamps are not, like here, allowing an easy sort). So it's not wasted ^^ (and still usefull, keep it on here. +1).

Comment: @bentoy13 - the day will always be the same which makes things simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I have also a fancy solution using awk:

```
awk -F ',' -v mytime="2013 07 30 22 09 00" '
  BEGIN {tlimit=mktime(mytime); lastline=""}
  {
    l_y=substr($1,0,4); l_m=substr($1,4,2); l_d=substr($1,6,2);
    split($2,l_hms,":"); l_hms[3]=int(l_hms[3]);
    line_time=mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", l_y, l_m, l_d, l_hms[1], l_hms[2], l_hms[3]));
    if (line_time>tlimit) exit; lastline=$0;
  }
  END{if lastline=="" print $0; else print lastline;}' myfile.csv
```

It is working based on making the timestamps from each line with awk's time function [`mktime`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html). I also make the assumption that `$1` is the date.

On the first line, you have to provide the timestamp of the time limit you want (here I choose `2013 07 30 22 09 00`). You have to write it according to the format used by `mktime` : `YYYY MM DD hh mm ss`. You begin the awk statement with making up the timestamp of your time limit. Then, for each line, you catch up year, month and day from `$1` (line 4), then the exact hour from `$2` (line 5). As `mktime` takes only entire seconds, I truncate the seconds (you can round it up with `int(l_hms[3]+0.5)`). Here you can do evereything you want to approximate the timestamp, like discarding the seconds. On line 6, I make the time stamp from the six date fields I have extracted. Finally, on line 7, I compare timestamps and goto end in case of reaching your time limit. As you want the preceding line, I store the line into the variable `lastline`. On exit, I print `lastline`; in case of reaching the time limit on the first line, I print the first line.

This solution works well on your sample file, and works for any date you supply. You only have to supply the date limit in the correct format!

**EDIT**

I realize that `mktime` is not necessary. If the assumption that `$1` is the date written as YYYYMMDD, you can compare the date as a number then the time (extracted with `split`, rebuilt as a number as in other answers). In that case, you can supply the time limit in the format you want, and recover proper date and time limits in the `BEGIN` block.

Comment: +1 for showing me some new stuff in Awk at least (mktime and substr). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` instead of your `grep` like this:

```
 awk -v FS=',' -v Hour=22 -v Min=9 '{split($2, a, "[:]"); if ((3600*a[1] + 60*a[2] + a[3] - 3600*Hour - 60*Min)^2 < 100) print $0}' file
```

and basically change the `100` to what ever tolerance you want.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to avoid doing it in awk if possible as I find the syntax clunky. I'm sure it's great if you use it all the time, but the likely use case here is for it to be passed as a one liner from inside R studio, so awk works less well. Good answer nevertheless.

Comment: +1 for awk, as it's probably the most concise, yet very readable, version. What Pascoe wants (use grep but on a search term that may NOT be contained in any of the lines) is unreasonnable: grep is clearly not suited in that situation.

Comment: Agree - I did say that I understand it's a pattern matching command. I was trying to find the command in bash with similar syntax that would handle it. I know it's not a timestamp in the eyes of bash, but equally I know I can grab a section of a file using sed, so I was hopeful there might be some compromise. As you can tell from my posts I am an amateur at this stuff.

Comment: @Pascoe - from someone whose been programming in UNIX for 30 years: learn awk NOW and save yourself a ton of headaches. Once you understand the `<condition> { <action> }` paradigm its a breeze, it's just that initial paradigm shift that's the hurdle but it's a pretty darn small hurdle. awk is THE right tool for almost every text processing application, except the trivial one-liners you can crank out in 5 seconds with grep and sed.

Comment: Thanks Ed - I believe you. And it is still something I am committed to. I just worry about spreading myself too thinly as I am currently learning bits and pieces in R, MatLab / Octave, C++, Bash, SQL and even occasionally still VBA